# web scraping of top 10 odi player

Tags: pandas, beautifulsoup, python-requests

table = soup2.find('table', {'class': 'table'})   rankings = {}   position = table.find('td', {'class': 'rankings-block__banner--pos'})   player = table.find('th',{'class': 'table-head__cell--player'})    team = table.find('th',{'class': 'table-head__cell--team'})   ranking = table.find('th',{'class': 'table-head__cell u-text-right'})    ranking[player] = {'position':position,'player': player, 'team': team,'ranking': ranking}
for row in table.find_all('tr', {'class': 'table-body'}):   position = row.find('td', {'class': 'table-body__cell table-body__cell--position u-text-right'}).text.strip()    player = row.find_all('td', {'class': 'table-body__cell u-center-text'})[0].text.strip()    team = row.find_all('td', {'class': 'table-body__cell u-center-text'})[1].text.strip()    ranking = row.find('td', {'class': 'table-body__cell u-text-right'}).text.strip()   rankings[player] = {'position': position,
'team': team,
'ranking': ranking}   rankings

getting output
IndexError: list index out of range

Comment: Hi @bishwajit bhattacharya please elaborate your code and  update with URL and explain what to extract from website just dont copy paste code here

Comment: @BhavyaParikh the url is https://www.icc-cricket.com/rankings/mens/player-rankings/odi and code i mentioned before i am webscraping  top 10 odi player getting error list index out of range

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
first_data=soup.find("div",attrs={"data-cricket-scope":"odi"}).find("div",class_="rankings-block__top-player").get_text(strip=True,separator=" ").split(" ")

other_data=soup.find("div",attrs={"data-cricket-scope":"odi"}).find_all("tr",class_="table-body")

final_lst=[]
final_lst.append(first_data)

for i in data:
    split_lst=i.get_text(strip=True,separator=" ").split(" ")
    final_lst.append(split_lst)
```

Ouptut:

```
[['1', 'Babar', 'Azam', 'PAK', '873'],
 ['2', 'Virat', 'Kohli', 'IND', '844'],
 ['3', 'Rohit', 'Sharma', 'IND', '813'],
 ['4', 'Ross', 'Taylor', 'NZ', '801'],
 ['5', 'Aaron', 'Finch', 'AUS', '779'],
 ['6', 'Jonny', 'Bairstow', 'ENG', '775'],
 ['7', 'David', 'Warner', 'AUS', '762'],
 ['8', 'Shai', 'Hope', 'WI', '758'],
 ['9', 'Kane', 'Williamson', 'NZ', '754'],
 ['10', 'Quinton', 'de', 'Kock', 'SA', '747']]
```